# venv does not work properly, or am I missing something?

Tags: python, python-venv

So I wanted to start to experiment with pythons virtual environments and got a problem from the beginning.

When trying to activate an environment nothing seems to happen. This is what a tutorial tells me to do:

> `venv\Scripts\activate`

This command is for Windows.

> Your shell prompt will change to show the name of the activated environment.

When running this command in my command promt, nothing happens. (I have created an venv before trying to activate it)
Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? Is this command only working on Windows 10? (Ive got Windows 7)

The tutorial I wanted to check out was this one

[Flask Tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/installation/#installation)

Comment: On windows you'll need `venv\Scripts\activate.bat` if using command prompt or `venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1` if using powershell. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

Comment: what shell do you use? i've seen the same thing in the git bash shell. In powershell or cmd the name of virtual environment was shown fine. probably it works well in the git bash too, just is not indicating the venv name

Answer (score 1):

So I basically tried all for me thinkable possibilities and this is what worked out for me:

```
. venv/Scripts/activate
```

So if you are using a bash console in visual studio basic you should give it a try.
Unfortunately I have no idea why this should or shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to source the activate file.

either:

```
source venv/Scripts/activate
```

or

```
. source venv/Scripts/activate
```